# ¿Crear cookie o algo para atraer a posibles clientes por instagram?

Tags: inteligencia-artificial, código-abierto

Me preguntaba si se puede hacer algun codigo, script o si existe alguna forma para atraer clientes con publicidad; cosa de aparecer en instagram como publicidad, o como puedo hacer que aparezca mi pagina o mi imagén publicitaria si alguien dice "x" (como funciona la publicidad hoy en dia; gracias a que los celulares escuchan me aparecen publicidades según de lo que hable... etc)

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Esto no es algo que se haga con programación, es algo que tendrás que contratar en instragram o en el medio que quieras aparecer. Las cookies no sirven para eso. Una cookie es un pequeño fragmento de datos que guardan los clientes web para facilitar las sesiones HTTP: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_(inform%C3%A1tica)

Comment: La publicidad hoy en día funciona casi de la misma forma que en el pasado o desde que la conocemos como tal: pagas a un medio publicitario para que publiquen tu anuncio. Tu pretendes saltarte el medio publicitario y claramente estás en desventaja. Ellos tienen todas la herramientas que tu no posees, además de ser dueños del medio en el que hacen la publicidad. Saludos